# Regular expression with backslash in Python3

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to match a specific substring in one string with regular expression, like matching `"\ue04a"` in `"\ue04a abc"`. But something seems to be wrong. Here's my code:

```
m = re.match('\\([ue]+\d+[a-z]+)', "\ue04a abc").
```

The returned `m` is an empty object, even I tried using three backslashes in the pattern. What's wrong?

Comment: `"\ue04a abc" == " abc"` -- there's no actual backslash in your string

Comment: @Rakesh Thanks, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backslashes in regular expressions in Python are extremely tricky.  With regular strings (single or triple quotes) there are two passes of backslash interpretation: first, Python itself interprets backslashes (so `"\t"` represents a single character, a literal tab) and then the result is passed to the regular expression engine, which has its own semantics for any remaining backslashes.

Generally, using `r"\t"` is strongly recommended, because this removes the Python string parsing aspect.  This string, with the `r` prefix, undergoes no interpretation by Python -- every character in the string simply represents itself, including backslash.  So this particular example represents a string of length two, containing the literal characters backslash `\` and `t`.

It's not clear from your question whether the target string `"\ue04a abc"` should be interpreted as a string of length five containing the Unicode character [U+E04A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e04a/index.htm) (which is in the [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas), aka PUA, meaning it doesn't have any specific standard use) followed by space, `a`, `b`, `c` -- in which case you would use something like

```
m = re.match(r'[\ue000-\uf8ff]', "\ue04a abc")
```

to capture any single code point in the traditional [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) PUA; -- or if you want to match a literal string which begins with the two characters backslash `\` and `u`, followed by four hex digits:

```
m = re.match(r'\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}', r"\ue04a abc")
```

where the former is how Python (and hence most Python programmers) would understand your question, but both interpretations are plausible.

The above show how to match the "mystery sequence" `"\ue04a"`; it should not then be hard to extend the code to match a longer string containing this sequence.

Comment: I see the difference. The substring should be interpreted as a unicode substring. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
import re
m = re.match(r'(\\ue\d+[a-z]+)', r"\ue04a abc")
if m:
    print( m.group() )
```

**Output:**

```
\ue04a
```

Comment: The m is still empty. I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: Add `r` before ""\ue04a abc""